# Is "bamboo grove" pronounced 竹林【ちくりん】 or 竹林【たけばやし】?

Tags: readings, wago-and-kango, multiple-readings

Is  "bamboo grove" pronounced 竹林【ちくりん】 or 竹林【たけばやし】?

I found some pages here

[https://www.weblio.jp/content/竹林#:~:text=竹林（たけばやし、ちくりん,、たかやぶ）とも言う。](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%AB%B9%E6%9E%97#:%7E:text=%E7%AB%B9%E6%9E%97%EF%BC%88%E3%81%9F%E3%81%91%E3%81%B0%E3%82%84%E3%81%97%E3%80%81%E3%81%A1%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8A%E3%82%93,%E3%80%81%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%84%E3%81%B6%EF%BC%89%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86%E3%80%82)

https://zatugaku-gimonn.com/entry2020.html

...but I do not see a clear indication of when to use one or the other.

Comment: It seems 日本国語大辞典 gives ちくりん, たけばやし, and たかばやし as equivalent options. But ちくりん is the main article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kango-reading (ちくりん) should be clearly more common in government documents and technical contexts, but both readings are natural in TV shows, novels, blogs and such, and it's a matter of taste. Some words can have different meanings depending on how they are read (e.g., [さんどう vs やまみち](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72177/5010) or [きょう vs こんにち](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17752/5010)), but that is not the case here. I personally think it's generally safe to always use ちくりん when in doubt.